# How to Host HTML on a different server than Heroku

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I have my index.html and the necessary .js files on heroku. Everything works fine. Now, I don't want to send my users to "myappname.herokuapp.com", so I plan to use my own website to store the .html file, but when the user taps "submit" on my HTML form, I want to execute the Herok NodeJS code.

Here is what the html looks like

```
<script>
  const form = document.querySelector("form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      displayStatus("processing...");
      const request = new Request("/file-upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(form),
      });
      const res = await fetch(request);
      const resJson = await res.json();
      displayResult(resJson.result);
    } catch (err) {
      displayStatus("an unexpected error");
      console.error(err);
    }
  });

  function displayResult(result) {
    const content = `Your ID: ${result.id}`;
    displayStatus(content);
  }

  function displayStatus(msg) {
    result.textContent = msg;
  }
</script>
```

How can I call this "/file-upload" from my HTML that is located on "mywebsite.com/index.html" while the actual NodeJS logic runs on "myappname.herokuapp.com"

I've tried to replace the "/file-upload" with "myappname.herokuapp.com/file-upload" but it doesn't work.

Again, the goal is to use what I have on Heroku, but not have the users go to "myappname.herokuapp.com" instead they should go to "mywebsite.com/index.html"

Thank you

Comment: why dont you just hookup the domain name to the heroku server? other then that you will have to have a get request to the heroku server  (from mywebsite.com) to then serve that index.html file

Comment: Yes, but I already have "mywebsite.com" fully established. It won't make much sense to connect this, if my simple Heroku app will replace my entire existing website.

Comment: When the user hits submit on the index.html, send an api request to the heroku server to do what you want with the data, the return it. However it appears you have that logic in a script tag, so you are wanting it to run on the frontend? then you might need to redirect the user to the heroku app. I dont think I am fully getting what you are asking here

Comment: "/file-upload" is POST request that I make from the frontend to Heroku (I have an index.js that processes this request). Because my current Heroku app has the index.html and index.js at the same location, the "/file-upload" works fine.

When I move the index.html to a different host (not Heroku), then "/file-upload" doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the server code? if you move the index.html, you have to go get it from where you moved it too.

Comment: the new location for index.html, doesn't support nodejs, that's the problem. if it supported, i could've simply ignore heroku and move all my files to my own host.

Comment: what is the new place? does it not support rest? If you cant get index.html then you cant serve it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, replacing "/file-upload" with "myappname.herokuapp.com/file-upload" did the trick. The only issue is my "const request = new Request" request returning an error all the time, but Heroku logs shows a successful execution of "file-upload"